# A problem related to integration in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

If $f\in L^1[0, 1]$ and $\int_{0}^1 x^nf(x)=0$ for all $n = 0,1,2,...$then prove that $f$ is identically zero almost everywhere.

This would be very easier to prove if $f$ were continuous on $[0, 1]$ by applying Stone–Weierstrass' theorem. Isn't it? Even I know every $L^1$ function is appropriated by continuous function. What can I use this fact here to prove this problem. I really need help.

Comment: this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1373959/251257 to a related question might be helpful

Comment: Maybe you can say $\int_0^1 x^nf(x) =\int_{[0,1] -E} x^n g(x)+ \int_E x^nf(x)$ , where $g(x)$ is continuous and $m(E) < \epsilon $.

Comment: @Gary: Surely you mean $m(E)<\epsilon$, as per Lusin's theorem.

Comment: @AlexR.: (Almost) Surely (ha-ha), of course, I should have said that. Let me edit.

Comment: Thanks Gary!  lusin theorem make it easier.

Comment: @Sarita: It was also AlexR 's idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using Weierstrass' approximation theorem, it follows that
$$
             \int_{0}^{1}g(x)f(x)dx = 0,\;\;\; g \in C[0,1].
$$
Define $g_{h}$ to be $0$ on $[0,y]$, to ramp linearly and continuously to $1$ on $[y,y+h]$, and to be $1$ on $[y+h,1]$. Then
$$
         \int_{0}^{y}f(x)dx =\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\int_{0}^{1}g_{h}(x)f(x)dx = 0.
$$
The above holds for all $0 \le y < 1$. By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem,
$\frac{d}{dy}\int_{0}^{y}f(x)dx=f(y)$ a.e., which means $f=0$ a.e..

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is the following: the function
$$ g_n(x) = \frac{2^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}(1-x^2)^{n} $$
is a polynomial of degree $2n$, with integral over $[-1,1]$ equal to one. $g_n(x)$ is concentrated around the origin, so that $g_n(x)$ converges in distribution to a [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). If $x_0$ is a Lebesgue point for $f(x)$, we have:

$$ f(x_0) = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\,g_n(x-x_0)\,dx = \lim_{n\to +\infty} 0 = 0 $$
hence $f\equiv 0$ almost everywhere.